# Directly proving continuous differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let us say that we want to prove that a function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on an open interval $I$ is continuously differentiable on $I$. One way to do this is to establish that $f'(x)$ exists at each point in the interval $I$, by examining the limit of $h^{-1}(f(x+h)-f(x))$ as $h \to 0$ for each fixed $x \in I$, and then showing that the now well-defined function $f': I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous by examining $f'(x+h) - f'(x)$ as $h \to 0$ for each $x \in I$. Is there a way to combine these two steps, directly showing continuous differentiability?

Comment: If you can show that the convergence $h^{-1} \cdot (f(x+h) - f(x)) \to f'(x)$ as $h \to 0$ is (locally) uniform, this will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f:I\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable if and only if the two-variable  limit 
$$
\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (a,a) \\ x\ne y}} \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \tag{1}
$$
exists for every $a\in I$.

Indeed, continuous differentiability implies the existence of (1) via the Mean Value theorem: the quotient is equal to $f'(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$.

In the converse direction, the existence of limit (1)  implies the existence of $f'(a)$ (since $y$ could be set equal to $a$). Suppose there is a sequence $t_n\to a$ such that $f'(t_n)$ does not converge to $f'(a)$. Then we can take $y_n=t_n$ and $x_n$ sufficiently close to $t_n$ so that 
$$
\frac{f(x_n)-f(y_n)}{x_n-y_n} - f'(t_n)  \to 0
$$
which implies the limit (1) does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the last part of the argument can also be stated more directly, without an appeal to contradiction.